# Why does jQuery ajax (post method) show encoded URL in the browser?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I was under the impression that the post method sent data to the .php page behind the scenes, and only the GET method showed the encoded url in the browser's address line.

I ask because I'm concerned with showing a users e-mail address in a browser address bar (encoded or not). I'm new to web-development with connected web-server, just wondering if this is a valid concern or not.

Comment: How does AJAX (behind the scene) and 'url in the browser's address line' are connected? Can't understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What you have said is correct POST should just post "behind the scenes" as you put it, but an experienced user could still see this information.

However it should not show up in the address bar!

Can you post your jQuery that is showing the url?

Comment: Just re-tested and it seems to be working as expected.  Not sure why I was seeing that behavior before -- I haven't chanced any of the code.  Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't think it would be a problem, if you used the GET method (which would show in the url address), but if your website needs some sort of security I would recommend encoding it and passing it on with POST.

Answer (score 0):

`POST` will never display anything about the data being sent in the address bar.
(but yes an experienced user (so called hacker :P) can always see the encoded post data sent.

Answer (score 0):

POST method doesn't show parameters in the URL while GET method does! If not, you have to check again which method do you actually use.